# Prevent main menu in shop to negatively affect internal link juice

Tags: seo, navigation, menu

When analyzing our shop system, all SEO tools complain unanimously that there are too many internal links. We have a main menu bar integrated into all shop pages, containing links to our about 900 categories and subcategories in a tree-like view.

Now, adding resonable text to the categories and linking to it's subcategories seems like a waste, as it is only one link in about a thousand, making the process a bit ridiculous.

Is there a way to tell search engines something like "This is only a menu, don't listen to all the links it contains" via HTML? We'd like to keep the menu as a navigation option for users used to it and not remove it just because the SEO analytics complain about it - usability over SEO, if you will.

How is this solved in general, without compromising the navigation option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly you should answer the question: which kinds of pages should rank? categories, sub-categories, product detail pages?
- Then change all unnecessary links (links from important to not important pages and links from not important to not important pages) from `a href` (GET) to `button` (POST)
- Then set all unnecessary pages to `noindex`

On this way you minimize the amount of pages and links only to those, which are important, should rank and transfer link juice.